# Python HTTP request: no adapters found

Tags: python, httprequest, python-requests

I'm trying to generate an http(s) request via Python Requests however I'm running into a problem:

```
No connection adapters were found for 'set(['http://www.example.com/target'])'
```

I'm attempting to make the connection like so:

```
url = ['http://www.example.com/target']
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
ver = False;
message = { bunch of json data }
curl_request(url,message,headers,ver)
```

With the curl_request API call being:

```
# API call to perform curl request and return resulting json status
def curl_request(url,message,headers,ver):
    requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(message), verify=ver, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
    return data
```

Comment: I'm not aware of requests using a list as the URL

Comment: It was literally that simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a string, not a set.

```
url = 'http://www.example.com/target'
```